# How to specify multiple input files for Tesseract when using the output PDF option (only works with 'parallel' on the command line)

Tags: ocr, bash

I am trying to tesseract all files in a directory to a pdf:

This command works fine:

```
ls * | parallel -j 4 tesseract {} {.} pdf
```

And produces a pdf for each input file.

However, I am unable to get it to work without the parallel method.

If I enter:

```
for i in * ; do tesseract $i $1 pdf;  done;
```

It doesn't produce any pdfs and instead creates a single file named `pdf.txt`

What is the best way create pdfs from the input files in a folder without using the parallel option.

I understand that parallel is more efficient, but I would like to have the option of running without parallel for comparison purposes. Tx!

Comment: If you're asking what are the bash shell's equivalents of the parallel command's `{}` and `{.}` placeholders, they'd be `"$i"` (or `"${i}"`) and `"${i%.*}"`

Comment: You can force `parallel` to run in serial: `-j1`. Also be aware of this https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/3109 when using `tesseract` in parallel. TL;DR: `export OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1`